# Camel-Cased Foreign Key Name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, uppercase

So I have an existing database that I'm trying to manipulate through ActiveRecord.  All of the column, table, and database names are camel-cased, ie. myColumnOne, etc.  This doesn't really pose a problem except that, when I was trying to define the associations between the tables, I can't get Rails to accept and leave my input for the foreign key names alone.

For example:  I'm trying to define an association between a table called cableModems and a table called cmModels, where 
   cableModem has_one :cmModel, :foreign_key => "cmModelId"

Rails seems to want to say that the foreign_key is actually cm_model_id.  Even if I input it the way I showed above.

My question is this: Is there any way to make Rails accept the casing?  Or do I need to go about this without the associations?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the Ruby on Rails API docs to trace the execution path for `has_one`, it's quickly become fairly clear that there is no quick and easy way to prevent the automatic de-camelCasing. With named scopes and one or two custom methods, you should be able to replicate the functionality of `has_one` fairly easily, so I would suggest foregoing the association for now, and possibly submit that as a ticket on the Rails [Lighthouse](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/overview).

Comment: Sorry about taking so long to get back.  This is completely accurate.  I just wrote a few quick methods, bypassing the helper completely, and it works find now.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Is your database really case-dependent? Wouldn't it just work if you wrote

```
has_one :cm_model, :foreign_key => "cmmodelid"
```

I would also make write your classes as follows:

```
class CableModem < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "cableModems" 
  set_primary_key "cableModemId" 
end
```

Does that help in any way?